How to fix this in phpmyadmin?
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
Filename: bankriset/filter.php
Line Number: 141
Backtrace:
File: /home/findme/findmeundip.org/application/views/bankriset/filter.php
Line: 141
Function: _error_handler
File: /home/findme/findmeundip.org/application/views/bankriset/filter.php
Line: 99
Function: get_jenis_pkm
File: /home/findme/findmeundip.org/application/controllers/Bankriset.php
Line: 166
Function: view
File: /home/findme/findmeundip.org/index.php
Line: 294
Function: require_once
I attempted to change the type of ID from 0 to 1 in the database through PHPMyAdmin. However, after making that change, I found that the option for the "Select Type of PKM" column on my website became blank or did not display the requested data, while options "A", "B", or "C" could display their data. Similarly, when I reverted the ID back to 0, the "Select Type of PKM" search option reappeared, but options "A", "B", or "C" were unable to display their data. How can I resolve this issue?
